# How to break lines into multiple lines in Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I know in Python one can use backslash or even parentheses to break line into multiple lines.

But somehow in pyspark when I do this, i do get the next line as red which kind of shows something might be wrong.

```
(conf.setAppName('Learnfit_Recommender')
 .set("spark.executor.memory", "10g")
 .set("spark.executor.cores",5)
 .set("spark.executor.instances",50)
 .set("spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead",1024)
)
```

EDIT 1: I changed the parentheses to backslash. And if you see the image, I see few '.' as red and even the sc variable is marked as red.

[image]

Is this the correct way to break lines in pyspark?

Comment: Did you try executing the file?

Comment: Well the file works. But my concern is it shows the following line sc=sparkContext(conf)   with sc as red. I am using jupyter notebook to run this

Comment: @avr pls check the edit

Answer (score 10):

You can use slashes and parenthesis

```
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Python Spark SQL basic example") \
    .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value") \
    .getOrCreate()
```

Edit: and an example from a Spark Submit job

```
./bin/spark-submit \
--master <yarn> \
--deploy-mode <cluster> \
--num-executors <2> \
--executor-cores <2> \
```

Comment: It looks like you have a `|` character, unless thats your cursor. I use PySpark in the Jupyter Notebook as well but why are you building it? You can simply append the Spark path to your bash profile. Also seems redundant to write `conf = conf`since you already specified it in your first line.

Comment: No thats the cursor. Bash profile I dont want to add since currently I am testing the settings. Once the right settings are found then I can add those to bash profile

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to add blank space before backslash in PySpark.

```
conf = SparkConf()

conf.setAppName('appName')\
.set("spark.executor.memory","10g")\
.set("spark.executor.cores",5) 

sc = sparkContext(conf=conf)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either backslash or parenthesis to break the lines in pyspark as you do in python.

You can find them used in official spark python examples in spark website [here](http://spark.apache.org/examples.html)